# Do 24pin motherboard wires have to be in a certain order?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, wiring, atx

I am wanting to sleeve all the wires in my new PC.  On my 24pin motherboard connection cable, I must remove the end plastic connector piece from all the wires to sleeve them all individually. I have a couple questions about this cable though.

1) When I put all the wires back into the connector, must they be in the same order they are in now?

2) In a couple spots there is actually 2 wires going into a single slot.  I am not sure what to do with those, do all 24pin motherboard connectors have some slots where 2 wires go in like that?

Comment: No, you don't *have* to put them back in the same order, but the power supply could fry your motherboard (and possibly also itself) if they're in the wrong order.  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answers

1. Yes
2. No

Answer (score 2):

Why not just buy some pre-sleeved wires? And yeah, they absolutely have to go back in the same holes. Different wires have different voltages, getting them mixed up will cause your computer to explode in a giant fireball. Well maybe not that dramatic, but very likely something will be damaged.